# Get Fonts through Flash ans JS

Tags: javascript, flash, mxmlc

I have to check all available fonts istalled on user's system. Therefore, I try to use [this tutorial](http://hasseg.org/blog/post/526/getting-a-list-of-installed-fonts-with-flash-and-javascript/). I compiled Fontlist.as with mxmlc compiler and included a JS file, which contains the `populateFontList(fontArr)` function.
I embed the SWF file with:

```
$("#flash").flash(
  {
    "src": "FontList.swf",
    "width": "1",
    "height": "1",
    "swliveconnect": "true",
    "id": "getfonts",
    "name": "getfonts"
   },
   { update: false }
);
```

If I open the page, it the SWF file will be embeded to the `<div id="flash"></div>` but the `populateFontList(fontArr)` function isn't fired.

Is there any trap which I fell in?

I would welcome every advise.
Many thanks!

Daniel

Comment: Are you testing it with a local html file or an online one ? Which browser are you using ? Could you put your js code ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem was, that it had been locally. See my answer for further explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. My problem was, that I testet it locally. I installed the Flash Debugger and realised, that there was a security error #2060. The solution was to add the local path to flash player's global settings:

[Global Settings](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html)